# return null on quarkus hibernate orm no result

Tags: quarkus-panache, quarkus-hibernate-orm

I am working on a project where I am using the Quarkus Hibernate ORM and running queries like the code below. Every time a query fails to find an entity, it throws a 500 error:

```
fun getByEmail(email: String): MutableList<Any?> {
    return try {
    em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email").setParameter("email", email).resultList
    } catch (e: Throwable) {
        mutableListOf()
    }
}
```

It is quite annoying to use a try catch every time the EM is used.

My question is if there is a way to disable the NoResultError and instead return null or in this case an empty list?

I tried to disable the error in my application.properties, but it did not work.

`quarkus.hibernate-orm.returning-null-on-no-result=true`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-kotlin</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
     <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mariadb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be getting a `NoResultException` when calling `getResultList()`; if you do, please open a bug report to Quarkus with a reproducer.

I suspect your actual code uses `getSingleResult()` instead? That's the only method that throws a `NoResultException` in the Hibernate ORM codebase.

If so, just use Hibernate ORM's `Session` to create your query and you'll be able to use `uniqueResult()` or `uniqueResultOptional()`.

Not sure how to do that in Kotlin, but I imagine something like this could work?

```kotlin
fun getByEmail(email: String): Any? {
    return session.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email = :email").setParameter("email", email).uniqueResult()
}
```

EDIT: and it would be even simpler if you were actually using [Panache](https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm-panache-kotlin), something like:

```kotlin
fun getByEmail(email: String): User? {
    return User.find("email", email).firstResult()
}
```